# probability hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An HR manager estimates that 35% of married employees in a large office complex have spouses whose employers provide dental insurance and 65% have spouses whose employers provide extended medical and drug insurance. Of those whose spouses have dental insurance, 90% have also extended medical and drug insurance.

a) What is the probability that a randomly selected married employee has a spouse who has both types of insurance?
Given:
Dental = 35%
Medical and Drug = 65%
Dental, medical and drug = 90% of medical and drug = 58.5%
So therefore, medical and drug ONLY = 6.5%

So the probability of (a) would be 58.5%?

b) What is the probability that a married employee has a spouse who has neither type of insurance?
Would this be ZERO? Since there is no mention of employees whose spouses are without insurance. Rather it states that all married employees have spouses who have SOME type of insurance.

I can't seem to use the nCr theorem when only percentages are given with no fixed range. I have been stuck on this since the past 60 minutes and I don't know where to start from. How can I use the nCr probability distribution theorem for this particular type of a question? Support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No ${}_nC_r$ involved, it is a *large* office. This is basically a "Venn diagram" problem.

Comment: We haven't even covered Venn diagrams in our class yet. How is this a Venn diagram problem? And what's the alternative way around it?

Comment: I will write out a solution. Too bad about lack of Venn diagram, it is very basic. Look it up, I find it too difficult to draw pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D$ be the event "spouse has dental insurance" and $E$ be the event "spouse has extended medical." The two events *overlap*: some spouses have both.

Note that $\Pr(D)=0.35$ and $\Pr(E)=0.65$. (These add up to $1$. That's an "accident," and perhaps deliberately chosen to increase confusion. Not nice!)

We are told that $90\%$ of the people in $D$ are also in $E$. So the probability of both is $(0.35)(0.9)$. That's the first answer.

For the second question, we want to find the probability of landing outside **both** $D$ and $E$.

Note that if we add $0.35$ and $0.65$, we have counted the people who are in both twice. so the probability that a person is in both $D$ and $E$ is
$$0.35+0.65-(0.35)(0.9).\tag{1}$$
The probability of landing outside both $D$ and $E$ is therefore $1$ minus the number in (1). This is
$$1-\left(0.35+0.65-(0.35)(0.9)  \right).$$
This happens to simplify considerably.

***Remark:** We are told something that lets us find that $\Pr(D\cap E)=(0.35)(0.9)$. That's the answer to the first question.

Now use the formula
$$\Pr(D\cup E)=\Pr(D)+\Pr(E)-\Pr(D\cap E)$$
to calculate $\Pr(D\cup E)$. For the second question, we want the probability of neither $D$ nor $E$, that is, the probability of the *complement* of $D\cup E$. This is $1-\Pr(D\cup E)$.

Comment: So can we simply use the formula for mutually exclusive events then?

Comment: The answer says explicitly that $D$ and $E$ are ot mutually exclusive. I mentioned in a remark at the end that I could use symbols if you are familiar with them. Are you? By the way, both answers you had mentioned are not correct.

Comment: But for the second question, the answer is ultimately the exact same as the first one. So that means that people who have both types of insurance at the same time land outside of both D and E? This is kinda confusing.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that, it is an artefact of the "accident" that the numbers $0.35$ and $0.65$ add up to $1$. The author should have chosen say $60$ instead of $65$ to lessen confusion. By the way, the problem said that $90\%$ of people who have dental have extended. You interpreted that as meaning that $90\% of people who have extended have dental. But that's not what it says.